# For how long can one rent lockers at Swiss train stations?

Tags: switzerland, luggage-storage, train-stations

There are lockers for luggage at many Swiss train stations. I would like to store luggage in one of them (in Brig) for three days, buy cannot find out what the maximum period for rentals is - does anyone know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that information is in fact not listed in full on public websites.

So I called them and asked about specifics at the **Brig train station**:

---

#### Storage duration

- Generally, the maximum storage duration is 24h
- However, you can extend the storage duration via supplementary payments before the 24h runs out, up to a maximum of **72h total**
- If a 24h period runs out without further payment, the contents will be locked and a red light on the locker should indicate that you need to pay again to access your contents
- After the total maximum of 72h runs out, the contents of the locker will be claimed by the baggage office and moved to the lost & found, and you'll have to pick them up there (for a fee, I assume)

---

#### Pricing

Prices and available sizes *do* vary between locations ([source *(german)*](https://www.ktipp.ch/artikel/d/sbb-schliessfaecher-preise-mit-ortszuschlag/)).

In Brig, there's two sizes of lockers *(width x height x depth)*:

- **Large** - 44x61x88cm - CHF 8.00 / 24h
- **Small** - 24x42x75cm - CHF 5.00 / 24h

*Source: [SBB Rail Service](https://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/services/sbb-customer-service/rail-service.html) (+41 900 300 300 (premium rate number, CHF 1.19 / min))*

---

#### Opening Times (Brig)

**Baggage Office**

```
Mon–Fri   07:00 – 18:30
Sat       07:00 – 18:00
Sun       08:00 – 12:00
          13:30 – 18:00
```

**Lost & Found**

```
Mon–Fri   07:00 – 19:00
Sat       07:00 – 18:00
Sun       08:00 – 12:00
          13:30 – 18:00
```

*Source: [SBB service opening hours (Brig)](http://www.sbb.ch/en/station-services/am-bahnhof/railway-stations/bahnhof-finden.posid.1609.html)*

**Note**: These opening times only refer to the *offices* (baggage / lost & found), access times for your locker are usually longer.

I couldn't get exact details for access times to lockers in the Brig station, but this page for [lockers in Zürich main station](http://www.sbb.ch/en/content/sbbshop/en/zuerich/09_ug1_zg_schliessfaecher.html) lists them as

```
Sat–Sun   24h
Mon-Fri   00.30–04.30 closed
```

so I assume the situation in Brig is at least similar.